# Как восстановить windows 10 в исходное состояние?

Tags: windows, восстановление, майнинг

Когда я перехожу в настройки системы и пытаюсь начать восстановление, меня просто выкидывает из настроек. Восстановить с внешнего носителя нет возможности. Что делать в таком случае?

Как раз недавно была замечена ошибка:

> "Error: The requested action with this object has failed."

Возможно от того и неполадки в работе системы?

Comment: *Что делать в таком случае?* Пробовать запустить процедуру восстановления. загрузившись с установочного диска.

Comment: У меня на ноуте нет дисковода

Comment: USB есть? Установочная флешка. Или USB-сидюковод.

Comment: Shift+Restart и так далее

Comment: @void может всё равно потребовать установочный диск/карту